# iPhone 5: How to upgrade from 7.0.4 to iOS 9 and above?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I have iPhone 5 which is running iOS 7.0.4, in Software updates section, it is showing I can upgrade to iOS 8.4.1, I've read on other sites that iPhone 5 can be upgrade to iOS 9 and one user on Apple forum even said that it can be upgraded to iOS 10 as well.

So why it is not showing me the last supported version? Or I have to first upgrade to 8.4.1 and only then it will allow me to upgrade to iOS 9?

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5 can [run iOS 10.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices)

You may need to do iOS upgrades in sequence, but I can't find definitive info on this.

You might want to [use iTunes on Mac or PC](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/HT204204) to update your phone to keep settings intact.

Comment: I've read somewhere that iPhone 5 runs slower on iOS 10 than iOS 9.